# Cloudfront https redirecting in chrome and firefox but not safari

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I recently set up cloudfront on my s3 bucket with a custom domain to redirect http to https.

I am seeing this work perfectly fine in chrome and firefox on my desktop computer. But when I try to load it in safari, any browser on my ios device, or cURL -  https requests hang forever, and http requests load but don't redirect as expected.

At the time of writing this, you can see this behavior with the url:

http://storage.flowtoys.com/poi4.png
(correctly redirecting in chrome + firefox, but not safari)

https://storage.flowtoys.com/poi4.png (loading securely in chrome + firefox, but hanging for ever in safari)

I have a configuration that is virtually the same for a different s3 bucket, and it is correctly redirecting to https in safari: http://app.flowtoys.com/index.html

These two urls have separate but virtually identical ssl certificates (only difference is the subdomain), both requested through aws certificate manager. They same settings on the S3 buckets (public read), the same settings in the certificate, and the same settings in the cloudfront distributions.

I can't figure out why they are behaving differently.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: It redirects for me - have you tried clearing your browser cache? Try incognito as cliche as it sounds

Comment: Are you sure http://storage.flowtoys.com/poi4.png redirects to https *in safari* for you? I tried in a private window, and I am still seeing the same behavior.

When requesting from the terminal via `curl https://storage.flowtoys.com/poi4.png  -o ~/Downloads/poi4.png` hangs forever, but `curl http://storage.flowtoys.com/poi4.png  -o ~/Downloads/poi4.png` works. This is not as expected.

Comment: Yes, it loads in HTTPS on Safari - curl output: https://snipboard.io/3d8Yxy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one of AWS's load balancers had an incorrect configuration somewhere down the line. It seemed like people in Asia were experiencing this issue, and people in the US were not.

I ended up removing and deleting the SSL certificate in AWS. I then created a new one, and attached it to the same CloudFront distribution exactly as before, and then after some number of hours, everything was working as expected everywhere.